# Combining the rest of an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to be able to combine the rest of an array in java that changes its length.
The equivalent that I know of is a list in Python where you enter `list[1:]` for example to display the rest of a list. How would I go about doing that here `String formattedOutput = (user+" : "+message+parts[3:]);` while also adding a space in between each of the parts of the list?

Comment: Did you look at Apache Common's ArrayUtils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering the syntax doesn't really allow that, you yourself need to iterate from the given index to the end of the array, and do the appending. Considering you are trying to create a String of all elements, you should use a `StringBuffer` rather than just mere concatenation. The following example should work:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(user);
sb.append(" : ");
for(int i = 3; i < parts.length; i++)
{
     sb.append(parts[i]);
     if(i < parts.length-1) //if you don't want a space after the last part
     {
         sb.append(" ");
     }
}
String formattedOutput = sb.toString();
System.out.println(formattedOutput);
```

Of course, you could make your own merger function which takes the index like this:

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(user);
    sb.append(" : ");
    appendFromArray(sb, parts, 3);
    String formattedOutput = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(formattedOutput);
}

private void appendFromArray(StringBuffer sb, String[] array, int index)
{
    for(int i = index; i < array.length; i++)
    {
         sb.append(array[i]);
         if(i < array.length-1) //if you don't want a space after the last part
         {
             sb.append(" ");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, I didn't think of appending the whitespace *before* the array's element. That would simplify my code by 4 lines. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

If the parts Array is a String array you can create a method that does it. For example:

```
private String stringFromArray(Array array, int start){
    String result = "";
    for(int i = start; i < array.length; i++)
        result += (" " + array[i]); //Make sure you have a white space before the array[i];
    return result;
}
```

and then call it like that

```
String formattedOutput = (user+" : "+ message + stringFromArray(parts, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with small arrays or performance is not an issue, you could use `arraycopy()` and then `Arrays.toString()`. I probably wouldn't recommend this in a production environment but it might be fine for some testing:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int size = 3;
int startIdx = 2;

int[] arrayPart = new int[size];
System.arraycopy(array, startIdx, arrayPart, 0, size);

System.out.println("Message: " + Arrays.toString(arrayPart).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```

Result:

> Message: 3, 4, 5